# Checking if a java Thread has been join()ed

Tags: java, multithreading

I would like to check whether a certain thread has already been joined.
In the code below I have threads that finish at different times and I would like to check whether a thread has terminated and not yet been joined.

Is there a good way of checking this?

```
while(!allJoined){
        allJoined=true;
        for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
        {
            try {
                if(!threadList[i].isAlive() && threadList[i].NOT_YET_JOINED() ) {
                    threadList[i].join(0);
                    System.out.println("Joined t-"+i);
                } else {
                    allJoined = false;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) { 
                System.out.println("MASTER: Child interrupted."+e); 
            } 
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { 
            System.out.println("Child interrupted."); 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't use sleep() here. It's inefficient. Look at using guarded blocks (http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html).

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether you have `join()`ed a thread is a part of **your** state, not the thread's state. Imagine: you could have several threads all trying to join a given worker-thread.

Why don't you keep a list of the threads you have already joined?

Then check that list before you `join` it.

```
Vector<Thread> joined = new Vector<Thread>();
for(int i=0;i<threadList.length;i++) {
  if(threadList[i].isAlive() && !joined.contains(threadList[i])){ 
     threadList[i].join(0);
     joined.add(threadList[i]);
  }
}
```

then use joined.size() to see if all are joined or not.

Comment: thanks, perfect. I assume after joining i will append the joined thread to the joined vector.

Comment: AFAIK, the underlying OS thread will remain in zombie state until it is joined. Therefore it really seems to me that it *is* a part of given thread's state, no?

Answer (score 1):

Make your `Runnable` objects also extend `Observable`. Have your main class implement `Observer` and register with them when you start them.

Before the threads return from `run()` method have them notify. This way you just join when they're ready and you know which ones you've joined. (You of course keep track of which are still running and which you've joined)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to simplify this pattern, use an ExecutorService

e.g.

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nThread);
for(int i=0;i< nTasks; i++)
   es.executor(new Runnable .... );

es.shutdown();
es.awaitTermination(timeoutSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

This will create a thread pool which can be smaller than the number of tasks, and wait for it to finish efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

do you need

```
Thread.getState()==TERMINATED
```

Comment: as soon as the thread finished it goes to TERMINATED, but I need a state for "JOINED" but thats not a return value for getState()

Comment: Join<--->Waiting Thread Finish......<--->Terminated. Peter needs to know if a thread is Joined, not Terminated.